# My app displaying 2 toolbars instead of one

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

When i testing my app through xcode in multiple devices, my app shows one toolbar as expected. After that i have uploaded the update of my app, in app store. But suddenly, I realized that in some iphones (ios 7.0.4), after app's update, on launching it cames with 2 toolbars.

I am adding the toolbar programmatically in `viewDidLoad` function of this controller.

```
UIImage* leftImg  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"left.png"];
UIImage* rightImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, leftImg.size.width, leftImg.size.height);
UIButton* lefButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UIButton* rigButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

[lefButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted];
[rigButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted];

[lefButton setImage:leftImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[lefButton setImage:leftImg forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[rigButton setImage:rightImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rigButton setImage:rightImg forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[lefButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadPrevChapter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[rigButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadNextChapter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *itemLeft  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:lefButton];
UIBarButtonItem *itemRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rigButton];
// In case i want to add Space between barbuttonitems
UIBarButtonItem *flexiableItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

// add items to toolbar
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:itemLeft, flexiableItem, itemRight, nil];
self.toolbarItems = items;
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];

UIImage *toolbarBgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:tlbImg];
UIImage *navbarBgImage = ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f) ? [UIImage imageNamed:navImgIos7] : [UIImage imageNamed:navImg];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbarBgImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:toolbarBgImage forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But i haven't added at navigation controller the toolbar this:

```
[[self navigationController].view addSubview:_toolbar];
```

as @Xeieshan said below.

Has anyone notice something like this before or does anyone know why this happening?

Screenshot of my app running on my iPhone 5 (v7.0.4)

[image]

Screenshot of my app, installed through appstore, after update, running on an iPhone 5 (v7.0.4)

[image]

Comment: Please post some code here, or we don't know how you added the toolbar.

Comment: @XhackerLiu sorry for late. I have updated the post with the code.

Comment: Have you tried installing the Release build from XCode? This is the first difference that comes into my mind on xcode install vs appstore install.

Comment: can u add the code were u actuall intializing ur toolbar. it help to find the problem

Comment: @CoolMonster I have already posted above. This is the initialization of toolbar.

Comment: @dimimpou where u actually initializing the toolbar and adding it to the view both statements are missing

Comment: @CoolMonster i have the initialization of tool bar but i am not added in the navigation controller. See my edit above.

Comment: @dimimpou can you say me what is height of left.png and width?  if it's too much big ,your toolbar  can appear repeatly.

Comment: Left & Right .png are both 41(w)x33(h) pixels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[self navigationController].view addSubview:toolbar];`
 This is how to add `UIToolbar` in `UINavigationController` but i cannot see your code where you do it?

I think you are adding `UIToolbar` on both `UIViewController` and `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I am not using this. I can't access now in my code, so i will test it in a couple of hours.

Comment: I have install the release and now i see the problem. But not yet understand why this happening. So, I will build again with your solution and before go for distribution i will run the release and let you know if problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against adding the toolbar to `UINavigationController.view`, as it breaks encapsulation (even though that's not enforced very much in UIKit).

Instead, add a custom root view controller containing the toolbar and a contained UINavigationController. This also allows you to properly layout the toolbar so that it doesn't cover the views in the navigation controller.